# DynamicQueryable for EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

LinqToSql examples contained an example to implement dynamic queries. With this you can provide a string containing the where clause and DynamicQueryable would convert this to a IQueryable. Does anything similar exists for EF Code First ?

Comment: [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) lets you dynamically build predicates that you can pass to `Where()` at runtime, but it works off composing compile-time Expressions, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DynamicQuery](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/DynamicQuery) library works with any provider.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, DynamicLinq does not allow me to pass a string containing the where clause... that means, I have to parse the string myself, which I was trying to avoid, since it can become quite complex!

Comment: I installed DynamicLinq, using nuget, but I guess I'm missing something... When I look at the methods available, you have for example DynamicLINQ.DynamicQueryable.DynamicWhere<T>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<T>, System.Func<dynamic,dynamic>), but how do you pass a string to it? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Super, that is exactly what I needed!